# pxe boot: tell client to try next boot option

Tags: pxe-boot, dhcpd

We have a setup using ISC dhcpd and tftpd to make UEFI PXE clients install their operating system. Once the system is up and running it automatically 'registers' the node by adding a line like this to the dhcpd.conf on the server within another group {} block:

```
host somehost { hardware ethernet 01:02:03:04:05:06; fixed-address 192.168.1.2; option host-name "somehost"; }
```

(with correct values for hostname, MAC and IP, of course)

That group has no configuration to provide any boot file.

The (indended) effect of this is that the system will not boot into the installation setup. Instead it tries to boot from network via pxe, does not get any bootfile and finally boots from disk (which is the next entry in the UEFI's bootlist).

Has been working like that for years and still does.

However, there's one drawback: everytime the client boots it will try PXE and will only boot from disk after hitting the PXE timeout, which is very long for some systems).

I would like to modify the dhcpd.conf in a way that it immediately tells the PXE code of the client to abort the PXE attempt and try the next boot entry.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Update: I tried to use the PXE_BOOT_MENU and PXE_BOOT_PROMPT options decribed here: https://web.archive.org/web/20061114170438/download.intel.com/design/archives/wfm/downloads/pxespec.pdf (Page 20/21) but it looks like the client ignores these:

```
       # Set PXE options:
       #    9 (PXE_BOOT_MENU; type 0 => local boot)
       #    10 (PXE_BOOT-PROMPT; timeout 0 => immediate boot)
       # see https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXE_native_boot_menu
       option vendor-encapsulated-options
           9:1:
             0:
           10:1:
             0;
```

Update2: It seems that Microsoft's `abortpxe.com` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/os-deployment/understand-pxe-boot) could be used for that. But I could not find a free replacement for that yet. Is there one?